# I want favorite button for different stories to work properly

Tags: php, database, laravel, if-statement

I am facing a problem in PHP Laravel project. 
I have a favorite button for stories. Different users will have an option to make favorite the story they liked. "Stories" and "Favorite_Story" have separate tables. I have fetched all stories from the stories table, and fav_story from "fav_story" table,  based on user_id.

This is my controller code

```
public function fanfiction(){
    $user_id = session('userid');
    $data['stories'] = DB::Table('stories')->orderBy('story_id', 'des')->get();
    $data['fav_story'] = DB::Table('favorite_story')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
    return view('fanfiction', $data);
}
```

This is my view code

```
@foreach($stories as $row)
    <?php $story_id = $row->story_id; ?>
    <article class="post excerpt">
        <a href="{{ url('read_fanfic/'.$row->story_id) }}" id="featured-thumbnail">
            <div class="featured-thumbnail">
                @if($row->img == '')
                <img class="img-responsive" width="30%" src="{{ url('public/uploads/fanfic/no_img.png') }}" alt="Story Image" />
                @else
                <img class="img-responsive"  width="30%" src="{{ url('public/uploads/fanfic/'.$row->img) }}" alt="Story Image" />
                @endif
            </div>                      
        </a>
        <div class="post-content" style="text-align:justify;">
            {{ $row->story_desc }};
            <h3>{{ $row->story_title }}</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="readMore">
            @if(Session('username'))
                @foreach($fav_story as $row1)
                    @if($row1->story_id == $story_id)
                    <a href="{{ url('member/fav_story/'.$row->story_id) }}" style="background:#59AAE1;" > Unfavorite</a>
                    @elseif($story_id)
                        <a href="{{ url('member/fav_story/'.$row->story_id) }}" style="background:#1dbf73;" > Favorite</a>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </div>
    </article>
@endforeach
```

The stories which are marked as a favorite story will show an unfavorite button with that specific story, which will be made favorite on again click on that button. The problem is, it shows both favorite and unfavorite button with that specific story and not button for favorite is shown which needs to have this button to make it as favorite.

Comment: Give every button a different `id` so an example would be `id="favorite-post1"` and then the unfavorite button would be the same `id="unfavorite-post1"` and continue that same process for all the other posts. You can also just give the buttons the `auto_incremented` ID of the post it belongs to in the DB. So if post 1 has an `auto_incremented` ID of 1 then it gets `id="1"` and continue.

Comment: Actually, all the posts/stories are dynamic, which will be added by different users. Each user has an option for favorite stories. I am only confused about the foreach loop if you see at my view code, I mentioned here. I have two separate tables. 1st tbl for stories and 2nd tbl for favorite_stories. In both tables, story_id is common field.

Answer (score 1):

try this

**Modify your query in your controller:**

```
// this will store all story ids in an array
$data['fav_story'] = DB::table('favorite_story')->where('user_id', $user_id)->pluck('story_id');
```

**Your blade view**

```
...
<div class="readMore">
    @if(Session('username'))
       @if(in_array($row->story_id, $fav_story))
           <a href="{{ url('member/fav_story/'.$row->story_id) }}" style="background:#59AAE1;" > Unfavorite</a>
       @else
           <a href="{{ url('member/fav_story/'.$row->story_id) }}" style="background:#1dbf73;" > Favorite</a>
       @endif
    @endif
</div>
...
```

**EDIT**

update `$row->id` to `$row->story_id`

Comment: is there any value in `Session('username')`? and can you dd `$data['fav_story']` for me?

Comment: Yes, there is a session('username') for a user who is logged in. So, if that specific logged user has marked a specific story as favorite so button should look as unfavorite otherwise the story which the logged in user didn't marked as favorite so the button should appear as favorite. Simply it is same as like/dislike button for each post for a specific user like in facebook. Hope you understand my problem